# ASP.Net Dynamically set width of TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview, width

I've got a tree view that can be anywhere from 1 level deep to nearly 6. Each node can be just a few letters or a couple of words totalling up to 20-30 characters.

How do I find the largest width of one of the node's text and add its depth offset to set the width of the treeview so it doesn't go through my borders?

If I need to add more info, let me know.

---

Edit:

Here's what I've currently got. I need to set the width of the panelLocations on page load so the tree view can load correctly inside of it.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelLocations" runat="server" style="position:absolute;border:solid 1px #E0E0E0;padding:10px 5px 5px 10px;background-color:#F7F7F7;width:350px;display:none;" >
    Search: <asp:TextBox ID="textboxLocationSearch" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="disabled" ToolTip="To find a store, type the 4 digit store number (e.g. 0001)" />

    <asp:Button ID="buttonFindLocation" runat="server" Text="Find" OnClick="buttonFindLocation_Click" OnClientClick="LocationSelected();" style="width:60px;"/>

    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="HideLocations();" style="width:60px;"/>

    <hr />

    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewLocations" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeViewLocations_SelectedNodeChanged" NodeIndent="10"></asp:TreeView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: How about css , or javascript ? 
Are you using one or all of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since web browsers will render the content differently, your only option to find out the **real** width of the content is to use javascript to traverse the DOM elements and measure the width.

The cleanest and simplest solution is to specify a suitably large width for the container element, then specify a value of `overflow:scroll` to allow extra-wide content to be scrolled. It's pretty ugly to see scroll bars around elements in the page, but when you're using a tree-view structure, ugly is something you live with.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the MeasureText method, in Graphics namespace. Basically it gives you back the size of a string supposed to be rendered in a certain font and size. Given a constant width for every intentation level (you know, tree lines, buttons/icons: you can measure it statically), you can assume needed width will be the largest of:

```
measuredText + (level * indentationWidth)
```

HTH!

Comment: That would be great if it was a winform. I'd be able to set the font as I needed and find the width, but this is a website. Different browsers shows text as different sizes. Also, the style sheet the user currently has selected can change the size of the font which the server wouldn't know about...